# VB.NET to C# Array of banned characters

Tags: c#, vb.net, character, special-characters

i have this array of banned characters in VB.NET how can i convert it?

Original VB.NET Banned Characters:

```
Public BannedChars() As String = New String() {" ", ",", ".", ";", "/", "\", "!", """", "(", ")", "£", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "{", "}", "[", "]", "@", "#", "'", "~", "<", ">", "?", "+", "=", "-", "|", "¬", "`"}
```

Tried C# Banned Characters but didn't work:

```
public string[] BannedChars = new string[] {" ", ",", ".", ";", "/", "\", "!", """", "(", ")", "£", "$", " % ", " ^ ", " & ", " * ", "{ ", "}", "[", "]", "@", "#", "'", "~", "<", ">", "?", "+", "=", "-", "|", "¬", "`"};
```

Errors:

```
CS1003  C# Syntax error, ',' expected

CS0623  C# Array initializers can only be used in a variable or field initializer. Try using a new expression instead.

CS0023  C# Operator '!' cannot be applied to operand of type 'string'

CS1056  C# Unexpected character '£'

CS0019  C# Operator '%' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

CS0019  C# Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'
```

Any helps apppreciated!
Thanks
C.

Comment: Saying that it didn't work is **NEVER** adequate.  It is incumbent on you to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation to us of what you're trying to achieve, how you're trying to achieve it and what happened when you try. Don't be lazy with your descriptions and expect us to guess or assume that which you already know.

Comment: Ehm oh sorry about it! I haven't checked that some text is missing of bottom of this topic!! Wait i'll update...

Comment: how can i represent in string special characters?

Comment: To be honest, I would tend to do this sort of thing this way: `var bannedChars = @" ,.;/\!""()".ToCharArray();`.  Using a verbatim string literal (with the `@` prefix) means that the string contains no escape sequences, so a backslash is just a regular character and the only escape needed is a VB-style double-quote. Using a `string` means that it's more readable than all the array elements and you also end up with a `char` array, which is probably more appropriate anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is *vague* one. If you want array of **characters**, use `char`, not `string` type:

```
  public char[] BannedChars = new char[] {
    ' ', ',', '.', ';', '/', '\\', '!', '\'', '(', ')', '£', '$', 
    '%', '^', '&', '*', '{', '}', '[', ']', '@', '#', '"', 
    '~', '<', '>', '?', '+', '=', '-', '|', '¬', '`'};
```

*escapement* is another issue: in C# we use `\` for this:

```
    '\\', '\''
```

In case you want a single **string** (which can be viewed as a readonly array of characters):

```
 public string BannedChars = new string(new char[] {
    ' ', ',', '.', ';', '/', '\\', '!', '\'', '(', ')', '£', '$', 
    '%', '^', '&', '*', '{', '}', '[', ']', '@', '#', '"', 
    '~', '<', '>', '?', '+', '=', '-', '|', '¬', '`'});
```

Finally, if you want **array of strings**:

```
 public string[] BannedChars = new string[] {
    " ", ",", ".", ";", "/", "\\", "!", "'", "(", ")", "£", "$", 
    "%", "^", "&", "*", "{", "}", "[", "]", "@", "#", "\"", 
    "~", "<", ">", "?", "+", "=", "-", "|", "¬", "`"});
```

please, once more, notice escapements (e.g. we don't double escaped quotation: not `""""`, but `"\""`):

```
 "\\", "\""
```

**Edit:** If you are going to check if a string contains any banned character, I suggest using `HashSet<char>` instead of array:

```
 // static : you have just one set of banned char, don't you?
 public static readonly HashSet<char> BannedChars = new HashSet<char>() {
    ' ', ',', '.', ';', '/', '\\', '!', '\'', '(', ')', '£', '$', 
    '%', '^', '&', '*', '{', '}', '[', ']', '@', '#', '"', 
    '~', '<', '>', '?', '+', '=', '-', '|', '¬', '`' 
 }; 

 ...

 string Mytext = @"some string with many characters: 'a', 'b'; which can be banned...";

 if (MyText.Any(c => BannedChars.Contains(c))) {
   // At least one Banned char has been found...
 }
```

Comment: thanks! but sorry for missed text in bottom! thanks!

Comment: I agree that using `char`/`Char` is a better idea than using `string`/`String`. It might require a change or two to the code that uses the arrays but that would likely make the code more correct.  For instance, testing whether a `string` contains any illegal characters would be as easy as `if (myString.Any(ch => BannedChars.Contains(ch))`.

Answer (score 2):

I can see the issue fairly clearly here but that may not always be the case, so please do provide better descriptions in future.

In this case, it is escaping that is the issue.  In VB, the double-quote is the only character that needs escaping in literal strings and that is done with another double-quote.  C# supports many escape sequences and the backslash is the escape character.  That means that you escape a double-quote with a backslash and you also need to escape a backslash with another backslash, e.g.

```
string[] arr = new[] {"\\", "\""};
```

I think that that should sort you out but we'll see if other issues arise after fixing that.

Answer (score 1):

C# uses lowercase keywords, so change `Public` to `public` and `New` to `new`.

C# puts types before variables instead of `As` clauses, so remove `As` and move `String` before `BannedChars`.

C# uses square brackets for arrays instead of parentheses, so replace `()` with `[]`.

C# puts declares array types with the brackets within the type rather than after the variable (legacy VB), so put `[]` after `String`.

C# allows omitting the base type of an array initializer rather than requiring the whole type or omitting it entirely along with the `new` keyword as VB does, so remove `String` from the initializer.

C# string literals take many forms. The closest to VB's are called verbatim strings and they are opened with `@"` and closed with `"` and stutter for literal " like VB does, so put `@` before every opening `"`.

C# terminates statements with a semicolon while VB does not (that's the simplest way to say it), so append a `;`.

```
public String[] BannedChars = new [] {
    @" ", @",", @".", @";", @"/", @"\", @"!", @"""", @"(", @")", 
    @"£", @"$", @"%", @"^", @"&", @"*", @"{", @"}", @"[", @"]", 
    @"@", @"#", @"'", @"~", @"<", @">", @"?", @"+", @"=", @"-", 
    @"|", @"¬", @"`" };
```

### .NET Datatypes (applies to Java, JavaScript, …)

As for what's a character: `String` holds zero or more characters. `Char` holds one character, a half or even less. `Char` is a UTF-16 code unit. `String` is a counted sequence UTF-16 code units. One or two UTF-16 code units represent a Unicode codepoint. A grapheme cluster is a sequence of one base codepoint followed by a sequence of combining codepoints. Text renders display grapheme clusters; users call them characters. Some codepoints are "composed" as in they are intended to mean the same thing as a different base codepoint with a specific combining codepoint. That makes comparing strings rather difficult. So, Unicode libraries provide normalization functions to either compose or decompose "composed" codepoints.

So, it appears that an array of strings could be a good choice for your code, especially since that's what the original code uses.